# Archive Portion of Hosted Email Quota

Tags: email, pop3

An account hosted by an email provider is nearing the limit of its quota (20GB). I want to fetch all but the last 6 months' worth of email, removing it from the server. IMAP is currently used to retrieve and check for email, but the server is also accessible via POP.

I've been told that `fetchmail` would be a good way to go about this, but how could I retrieve only a fraction of the used quota using said application? By *fraction*, I mean all mail within a certain range of dates.

Comment: Many email clients have the option to in addition to IMAP folders create a local data file to store your email and you can then in your mail client select move/copy messages as desired and subsequently delete them from your imap account, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Outlook-Data-File-pst-to-save-your-information-17a13ca2-df52-48e8-b933-4c84c2aabe7c

Comment: @HBruijn Sorry, just realized that my use of the word *manually* in the title might have been misleading. I'm not the user in question and do not want to setup an MUA (neither locally nor on a server) to accomplish what, to my mind, should be done programmatically. Also, why did you migrate this? I would have thought that email administration fit as a topic on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

I would move with a MUA the oldest messages in a specific folder (/say TO_BE_DOWNLOADED) and then sync the folder with offlineimap (http://www.offlineimap.org/).